# Scala Future Sequence Mapping: finding length?

Tags: scala

I want to return both a `Future[Seq[String]]` from a method and the **length** of that `Seq[String]` as well. Currently I'm building the `Future[Seq[String]]` using a mapping function from another `Future[T]`.

Is there any way to do this without awaiting for the Future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` over the current `Future` to create a new one with the new data added to the type.

```
val fss: Future[Seq[String]] = Future(Seq("a","b","c"))
val x:   Future[(Seq[String],Int)] = fss.map(ss => (ss, ss.length))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you somehow know what the length of the `Seq` will be without actually waiting for it, then something like this;

```
val t: Future[T] = ???

def foo: (Int, Future[Seq[String]]) = {
  val length = 42 // ???
  val fut: Future[Seq[String]] = t map { v =>
    genSeqOfLength42(v)
  }
  (length, fut)
}
```

If you don't, then you will have to return `Future[(Int, Seq[String])]` as jwvh said, or you can easily get the length later in the calling function.